# BackgroundColor мешает установить cornerRadius для TextView (xml)

Tags: c#, android, xml

Всем привет.
У меня есть TextView, к которым я с помощью MvxBind устанавливаю нужное значение цвета "BackgroundColor Select, Converter=BackgroundConverterColor", в зависимости от значения в property "Select". Так же, мне нужно установить закругления для этой textView. Я это делаю с помощью android:backgroud="@drawable/cornerRadius"

cornerRadius.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#D8FFA2"/>
    <stroke android:width="1.5dp"
            android:color="#cf975d"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
             android:topRightRadius="8dp"/>
</shape>
```

При этом всём, когда я убираю MvxBind - закругление работает. Когда включаю - нужный цвет устанавливается, но закругление не работает

BackgroundConverterColorConverter.cs:

```
public class BackgroundConverterColorConverter: MvxColorValueConverter<bool>
    {
        protected override Color Convert(bool value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is true)
                return Color.White;
            return Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему, чтоб и цвет нужный устанавливался, и закругление работало

Comment: Просто интересно, почему не Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Так сложилось исторически...

Comment: Не понятно как и что вы устанавливаете и что такое MvxBind, но скорее всего когда вы пытаетесь установить "новый цвет" вы просто устанавливаете сплошной а не ShapeDrawable, попробуйте цвет менять через Tint методы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно поздно но ведь лучше поздно чем никогда) И так я был для TextView (и не только для него)  создал отдельный класс где я просто буду указывать параметр через XML.

Для начала создайте такой класс:

CustomTextView.java

```
package com.example;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import androidx.annotation.ColorInt;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.example.R;

public class CustomTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {

public CustomTextView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    setBackground(new GradientDrawable());
    setBackgroundColorTint(null);
    setCornersRadius(null);
}

public CustomTextView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setBackground(new GradientDrawable());
    setBackgroundColorTint(attrs);
    setCornersRadius(attrs);
}

public CustomTextView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setBackground(new GradientDrawable());
    setBackgroundColorTint(attrs);
    setCornersRadius(attrs);
}

private void setBackgroundColorTint(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);

        ((GradientDrawable) getBackground()).setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomTextView_backgroundTintC, Color.TRANSPARENT));
        a.recycle();
    } else {
        ((GradientDrawable) getBackground()).setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // default color if not defined
    }
}

private void setCornersRadius(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        final TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);

        float radius = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomTextView_cornersRadius, 0);
        float[] radii;

        if (radius <= 0) {
            float radiusTopStart = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomTextView_cornerRadiusTopStart, 0);
            float radiusTopEnd = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomTextView_cornerRadiusTopEnd, 0);
            float radiusBottomStart = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomTextView_cornerRadiusBottomStart, 0);
            float radiusBottomEnd = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CustomTextView_cornerRadiusBottomEnd, 0);
            radii = new float[]{
                    radiusTopStart, radiusTopStart,
                    radiusTopEnd, radiusTopEnd,
                    radiusBottomStart, radiusBottomStart,
                    radiusBottomEnd, radiusBottomEnd
            };
        } else {
            radii = new float[]{
                    radius, radius,
                    radius, radius,
                    radius, radius,
                    radius, radius};
        }

        if (getBackground() instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) getBackground();
            background.mutate();
            background.setCornerRadii(radii);
        }

        a.recycle();
    } else {
        GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable) getBackground();
        background.mutate();
        background.setCornerRadius(0); // default radius if not defined
    }
}

public void setBackgroundColorTint(@ColorInt int color) {
    ((GradientDrawable) getBackground()).setColor(color);
}

public void setCornersRadius(float radius) {
    ((GradientDrawable) getBackground()).setCornerRadius(radius);
}
}
```

Затем создайте в папке res>value файл под названием attrs. В него поместите этот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
    <attr name="backgroundTintC" format="color" />

    <attr name="cornersRadius" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="cornerRadiusTopStart" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="cornerRadiusTopEnd" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="cornerRadiusBottomStart" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="cornerRadiusBottomEnd" format="dimension" />

</declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Затем вы можете использовать его в своём макете примерно вот так:

```
<com.example.CustomTextView
    app:backgroundTintC="@color/red"
    app:cornersRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello world"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Или программно вот так:

```
textView.setBackgroundColorTint(Color.RED);
textView.setCornersRadius(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics()));
```

Если у вас на макете не показываются изменения скомпилируйте приложение и у вас всё отобразится. В моём случаи всегда помогает. Если не поможет то тогда зайдите в Select Design Surface и нажмите там Force refresh layout